# Por que inserir uma linha em branco no final do código?

Tags: quebras-de-linha, convenções

A maioria dos linters de diferentes linguagens de programação, como o RuboCop (Ruby) e o JSLint (JavaScript) recomendam uma linha em branco do final de todos os arquivos de código. Como exemplo, o RuboCop:

> **RuboCop::Cop::Style::FinalNewLine**
>   Esse *cop* reforça a presença de uma linha final em branco em cada arquivo de código-fonte. [(adaptado de RubyDoc)](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/FinalNewline)

Além dos *linters*, até o Git, ao rodar o `git diff`, indica quando não há uma linha em branco no final dos arquivos de código:

> No newline at end of file

Para ilustrar, o resultado é:

```
1 def say_hi
2   puts 'hi'
3 end
4
5 say_hi
6
```

É só uma convenção? Existe diferença em colocar uma linha em branco no final do meu código e não colocar?

Comment: Relacionada na SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287967/1452488

Comment: Também temos a influência unix, em que sempre há quebra de linha no final de um arquivo texto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com [as normas POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) definidas pelo IEEE, uma linha pode ser definida da seguinte forma:

> Uma sequência de 0 ou mais caracteres desde que não seja o caractere de nova linha terminando com um caractere de nova linha

```
isso não é considerado uma linha

isso é considerado uma linha\n
```

Ao trabalhar com ferramentas padrões do Unix por exemplo, caso não exista essa quebra de linha no final, alguns problemas podem aparecer.

Um exemplo é a concatenação de arquivos usando o comando cat:

```
$ more a.txt
texto1$ more b.txt
texto2
$ more c.txt
texto 3
$cat *.txt
texto1texto2
texto3
```

Em sistemas não compátiveis com o padrão POSIX os arquivos geralmente não são terminados com uma nova linha.

Uma outra utilidade desse padrão definido pelo IEEE é que ao utilizar o atalho para ir ao final do arquivo no VSCode, caso a última linha seja grande o curso se posicionará no último caractere desse linha, caso exista uma linha em branco no final do arquivo o cursor irá se posicionar na mesma, podendo ainda visualizar as outras linhas existentes sem ter que utilizar a barra de rolagem horizontal para voltar ao início da linha.